# How to change css property 'margin-left' with integer value on property with string value "color' using Jquery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My purpose make the border color by green or any other color.
In my case i have used just color border but i want to filling color into the value of css property using same method like in Photoshop tool 'Paint Bucket'
For example, if go to browser and inspect code you will see indentation from left side of it's css: margin left: 15px. Therefore i need to use this property and filling it by color.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('p').each(function (index, el) {
        if ($(this).css('marginLeft') === '15px'){
            $(this).css({borderLeftStyle: "solid",
            borderLeftColor: "green"
            })
        }
    });
});

//Things to replace:

//Replace ".p" with your selector.
//Replace CSS property and value with what you are looking for.
//Replace "css()" with what you want to execute on that //found element.
```

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Helvetica, sans-serif;  }

.wrap{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px auto 100px;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
}

section{
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
}

article{
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

img{
    max-width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
}

time{
    font-family: Menlo, Monaco, monospace;
    display: block;
    color: #beaaae;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;}

h2{
    margin-bottom: 2px;  }
p{
    margin-left: 15px;
    line-height: 25px;  } /*TODO: space between text*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<section>
        <article>
            <h2>Connect GitHub to the project</h2>
            <time class="time">January 11 2018</time>
            <p><strong>Notice:</strong> Registration on website <code>https://github.com/</code><br>
                Go to the setting of IDE select bookmark <em>GitHub</em> input personal data in given field.<br>
                Where's <em>Host</em> it's <code>github.com</code> and <em>password</em> it's password on website/<br>
                Then press <em>Test</em> for successful connection to website.
            </p>
        </article>
    </section>
<html>
```

EDIT: Example image from answer instead of edit.

[Margin indentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90Nso.jpg) 
It's space between left corner and right. I want to instead of "margin" using or filling this area by color.

Comment: I can't understand what you want. Can you explain clearly what you are trying to do?

Comment: just use `border-left-width: 15px;` instead `margin-left: 15px`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the margin color of only one side. Since you've already used the left border to add green color, you can make the border `15px` thick and remove the margin:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').each(function(index, el) {
    if ($(this).css('marginLeft') === '15px') {
      $(this).css({
        borderLeftStyle: "solid",
        borderLeftColor: "green",
        borderLeftWidth: '15px',
        marginLeft: '0'
      })
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto 100px;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

section {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

article {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

img {
  max-width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
}

time {
  font-family: Menlo, Monaco, monospace;
  display: block;
  color: #beaaae;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

p {
  margin-left: 15px;
  line-height: 25px;
}


/*TODO: space between text*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<section>
  <article>
    <h2>Connect GitHub to the project</h2>
    <time class="time">January 11 2018</time>
    <p><strong>Notice:</strong> Registration on website <code>https://github.com/</code><br> Go to the setting of IDE select bookmark <em>GitHub</em> input personal data in given field.<br> Where's <em>Host</em> it's <code>github.com</code> and <em>password</em>      it's password on website/<br> Then press <em>Test</em> for successful connection to website.
    </p>
  </article>
</section>
<html>
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the green border and add another color to its left, you can add a container to your `p` and set its background color to the color you want. Don't forget to set the original background color to your `p` otherwise it will take the background color of its container:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').each(function(index, el) {
    if ($(this).css('marginLeft') === '15px') {
      $(this).css({
        borderLeftStyle: "solid",
        borderLeftColor: "green",
        backgroundColor: "#f8f8f8"
      }).parent().css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto 100px;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

section {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

article {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

img {
  max-width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
}

time {
  font-family: Menlo, Monaco, monospace;
  display: block;
  color: #beaaae;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

p {
  margin-left: 15px;
  line-height: 25px;
}


/*TODO: space between text*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<section>
  <article>
    <h2>Connect GitHub to the project</h2>
    <time class="time">January 11 2018</time>
    <div>
      <p><strong>Notice:</strong> Registration on website <code>https://github.com/</code><br> Go to the setting of IDE select bookmark <em>GitHub</em> input personal data in given field.<br> Where's <em>Host</em> it's <code>github.com</code> and <em>password</em>        it's password on website/<br> Then press <em>Test</em> for successful connection to website.
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
<html>
```

Note: both solutions above can be done in pure CSS, but I followed your way of doing it in jQuery. Also the container of the second solution can be added in jQuery instead of HTML if you like.

Comment: Thank you for previous answer.
I have last question: how to add indent from border to the text?

Comment: Use the `padding-left` CSS property (`paddingLeft` in JavaScript/jQuery).

Comment: Can I ask one more question? How can zoom in and out image use Jquery. I do like that:                                                                   
        $('img').on('click', function () {
        $(this) .css({
            transform: 'scale(2)'
        }).on('click', function () {
            $(this).css({
                transform: 'scale(1)'
            })
        })
    }) but it work just one time when zoo in and out and one more doesn't work